# Clean up WMI processes after closing the app

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a program that calls several WMI queries on different threads, like the code below. This code creates several WMI process, how can I close terminate those WMI processes when the application is closed?

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
               Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => StartWMIProcess()));
               th.Start();
           }
       }

       static void StartWMIProcess()
       {
           double cpuUsage = 0;
           ObjectQuery objQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
           using (ManagementObjectSearcher mngObjSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objQuery))
           {
               foreach (ManagementObject obj in  mngObjSearch.Get())
               {
                   //Process.
               }
           }
       }
```

I tried to Kill the WMI processes and restart the service, but I need administration rights.

Comment: Don't, it's not your responsibility - the OS will manage WMI just fine on its own